# How to open a files that's currently in Trash

Tags: macos, mojave, trash

How do I open files that are in Trash? I have put some MKV video files in Trash. I want to watch the videos (I use IINA).

How can I watch the videos without moving them out of Trash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid the message, e.g., "The document “Filename.mkv” can’t be opened because it’s in the Trash. To use this item, first drag it out of the Trash.", and open the *target file* without having to remove it from the **Trash**, do the following:

1. Open **INNA**, so it's window is showing.
2. Open the **Trash**.
3. *Drag* and *drop* the *target file* from the **Trash** onto **INNA**'s *window*, and it will play.

Note: If **INNA** is open without a *window*, you can *drag* and *drop* the *target file* from the **Trash** onto **INNA**'s **Dock Tile**, and it will play.

---

Another method to use for *apps* that will not respond to *drag* and *drop* on its *window* or **Dock Tile**:

1. Open the **Trash**.
2. Open **Terminal**.
3. In **Terminal**, use the `open` *command*:

If the *target app* is the *default app* for the *target file* you can do the following:

- Type `open` followed by a *space*, then *drag* and *drop* the *target file* from the **Trash** onto the **Terminal** window, and then press: <kbd>enter</kbd>

Or, if it's not the *default app* for the *target file* you can do the following:

- Type, e.g., `open -a IINA` followed by a *space*, then drag and drop the *target file* from the **Trash** onto the **Terminal** window, and then press: <kbd>enter</kbd>

Note in some cases, depending on the *app* and its location, you may have to use its *path* as well:

- Type,  e.g.,`open -a /Applications/IINA`, adding `.app` if necessary, followed by a *space*, then drag and drop the *target file* from the **Trash** onto the **Terminal** window, and then press: <kbd>enter</kbd>

---

Note: **IINA** does also have a *command line interface*, e.g.:

```
/Applications/IINA.app/Contents/MacOS/iina-cli
```

You can use the `-h` or `--help` *argument* to display its builtin help.